# Stimulus JS controllers not connecting. Rails 7 // importmap // stimulus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, turbo, import-maps

I recently got rid of `webpacker` and installed `importmap` and `turbo`. My Stimulus JS controllers are not rendering anything.

```
importmap.rb :
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.js", preload: true
```

```
typewriter_controller.js :


import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

  connect() {
   // some code...
  }
}
```

```
application.html.erb:


 <head>
     some stuff..

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "turbo", type: "module-shim" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
 </head>
```

I tried to re-install the stimulus gem but it didn't work. I'm running out of ideas on this one.

Comment: Do you register you js controllers in javascript/index.js ??

Answer (score 0):

As from the [`stimulus-rails` installation guide](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails), I would check the following files are configured this way:

###### In `app/javascript/controllers/index.js`

```
import { application } from "controllers/application"

// Eager load all controllers defined in the import map under controllers/**/*_controller
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

###### In `app/javascript/controllers/application.js`

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }
```

###### In `app/javascript/application.js`

```
import "controllers"
```

This assumes you are indeed using `importmap` and not some other JavaScript bundler (e.g., `yarn`).